# Change hashtag before call javascript function

Tags: jquery, html, hashtag

I have a simple html link: `<a href="#about">`.
The current URL is `http://www.example.com/whatever.html#info`.
And I have a simple jQuery code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   alert(window.location.hash);
});
```

Now, when I click on the link, it display me the old hashtag (info). But I want, when I click on the link then it should display me the new hashtag (about).

Is there a easy way to change the value of the hashtag before I call the jQuery code?

*Note I*:  This is just simplification of my target. I know it doesn't make any sense, but I need it.
*Note II*: Because of the proxy settings of my employer, I can't serve you a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$(this).attr('href')` to get the link tag's href.

```
$('a').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

and `$(this).attr('href').substring(1)` should return you `about` without `#`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nhPn5/

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setTimeout` to run your code in a later tick of the event loop, after the browser has performed the navigation:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    ...
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to change the text in the `a` tag. You can do this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('href','#about');
   alert(window.location.hash);
});
```

this way you will change the `href` from `#info` to `#about`.
Hope this is what you looked for.